# REGEXP_LIKE in DB2 v7r1 (7.1?)

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

From,

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzregexp_like.htm

```
SELECT PID FROM PRODUCT 
 WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(pid,'[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}')
```

But when I run a similar command,

```
SELECT MYCOLUMN FROM MYTABLE 
 WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(MYCOLUMN,'[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}')
```

I get

> SQL State: 42601 Vendor Code: -104 Message: [SQL0104] Token
>    was not valid. Valid tokens: < > = <> <= !< !> !=
>
> > = ¬< ¬> ¬= IN.  Cause . . . . . :   A syntax error was detected at token .   Token  is not a valid
> >     token.   A partial list of valid tokens is < > = <> <= !< !> != >= ¬<
> >     ¬> ¬= IN.   This list assumes that the statement is correct up to the
> >     token.   The error may be earlier in the statement, but the syntax of
> >     the statement appears to be valid up to this point.  Recovery  . . . :
> >     Do one or more of the following and try the request again: -- Verify
> >     the SQL statement in the area of the token . 
> >     Correct the statement.  The error could be a missing comma or
> >     quotation mark, it could be a misspelled word, or it could be related
> >     to the order of clauses. 
> >     -- If the error token is , correct the SQL statement because it does not end with a valid clause.

Is there any reason why this example does not work? Is IBM v7r1 not the same as 7.1?

Comment: Confirm which version of DB2 you are under:

`SELECT GETVARIABLE('SYSIBM.VERSION') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1`
or
`SELECT * FROM SYSIBMADM.ENV_INST_INFO`

Comment: Neither of those work =/

Comment: my SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 table is just one column IBMREQD with one row 'Y'

Comment: The first command also fails on GETVARIABLE with `GETVARIABLE in *LIBL type *N not found.`

Comment: I was trying to confirm the actual version you are running, the test are valid for `zOS` and `LUW`.  I don't know what the version check would be for `iSeries`

Comment: `select * from SYSIBM.SYSVERSIONS`

Comment: `SYSVERSIONS in SYSIBM type *FILE not found. `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

7.1 and v7r1 are the same thing...

The regular expression support was added as part of technology refresh (TR) level 9

From a command line, use the Work with PTF Groups (WRKPTFGRP) command

```
WRKPTFGRP PTFGRP(SF99707) PTFGRPLVL(*INSTALLED)
```

Also, you need to have 5770-SS1 Option #39 International Components for Unicode insallted.  You can use the Display Software Resources (DSPSFWRSC) to check for that.

If that's not installed, you'd see a message:
SQL0204 - QQQSVREG in QSYS type *SRVPGM not found.

Comment: SF99707 shows level 6, so thank you!

Thanks for your answer. Learning more every day... DSPSFWRSC on that option is installed.

Comment: May I ask how you found (or knew) that it was a part of the TR level 9?

Comment: I mean I see it now at [link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/IBM%20i%20Technology%20Updates/page/IBM%20i%207.1%20-%20TR9%20Enhancements) but... without the keyword TR I was lost.

Comment: @CodyG. I just knew that it hasn't always been available...so I went looking to find when it had been added.  7.1 is when IBM started using more frequent  TR's instead of full OS updates.

Comment: @CodyG. - The V7R1 notation is understood but outdated. It's a holdover from the past. It's definitely more correct to say 7.1.

Comment: @JohnY that's true from a marketing perspective, but the system still refers to OS levels in using the VxRxMx convention.

Comment: @DavidG - That's purely because it would be a pain in the ass for very little benefit to "fix" the green screens and other internal references. All I'm saying is that, in prose, it is *more* correct to say 7.1 than it is to say V7R1. If you want to use V7R1, OK, but that's like saying the latest version of Java is 1.8.

Comment: @JohnY plus it would break a lot of software that depends on the VxRxMx notation.  I agree, in conversation 7.1 would be the appropriate way to refer to it, but in code V7R1M0 is the only thing that works.